# Will web crawlers detect these jpegs in php password protected pages?

Tags: php, passwords, jpeg, web-crawler

Will web crawlers be able to find jpegs/images if the following occurs?

1. Page uses php `$_SESSION` as password protection.
2. Before page loads, webpage checks if correct password in `$_SESSION`
3. If password is correct, page loads, loading .jpegs
4. If password is not correct in `$_SESSION` page doesn't load, instead does a `METAREFRESH`
   using `if` statesment...
   so the crawlers cannot access the `.jpgs`

I do not want the images to be able to appear in google/yahoo/bing/etc image search.
I have read a lot about SEO/robots/crawlers but I am unsure about this.

Is this right?

Comment: I'm not 100% clear on what you're asking, but never do what you're describing in #2. Use a database to store the passwords

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Googlebot can't crawl pages behind a auth, though the best to get your content protected from any SE, is creating a deny list in a file called robots.txt (http://www.robotstxt.org/), located on the root if your site. There you can specify wich page will not be
crawled.
Also, putting rel="no follow" in any link, will make SEs not follow the link.,

Answer (score 1):

If the page is using password protection stored in the session the bots/crawlers will not find images no.

But that of course depends on how you handle the bots, if you have say a member area where you don't want bots to be snooping around, i suggest that you send unauthorized clients a 302 response and transfer them to a login page before any other content is delivered.

Comment: are you sure there is no backdoor / filetree that they could access?

Comment: There is no way for listing files unless you allow directory listing, the bots will not try to find /images/image01.jpeg and so on, you can watch how the bots crawl simply by looking at the access log.

Comment: However note that if you if your site shows images and then checks if the $_SESSION password is the correct one, and then if not gives the clients a metarefresh with redirection then yes, the bot will know of the filepath for the images on your page but i dubt that it will make use of it.

Comment: I'm wondering that because a direct URL like www.mysite.com/x/image01.jpg is accessible without a password. Crawlers won't find that, right?

Comment: No images are shown before the refresh, the php logic / meta refresh comes even before the head is loaded.

Comment: the meta refresh is handled client side, you want it to occur server side, take a look at this http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Comment: I don't see how using header instead of a metafresh is the better choice?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38813/discussion-between-ogelami-and-user2118228)

Answer (score 1):

I guess your PHP password protected pages simply "fetch" the url of these images( which might be arbit or db stored )

but if there are static content which can be otherwise accessed ( provided the link ), then web crawlers will eventually find it.

I suggest you to use a robot file instructing web-crawlers to ignore the static content in a particular folder.